# Filtering into specific class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I was doing something like this using BeautifulSoup:

```
for name in soup.find_all('div','name'):
```

When I am using this filter, my understanding is that I will get all the `div` tags with the attribute or class name `name`.

However, I don't want every instance of the `div` tag with the attribute `name`. I want certain instances in which they locate in a certain subtree of the HTML file. More specifically, instances within the tag `<u1 class="list-box mb-3 spacer">...<u1\>`, which is two levels above the tags I am looking for. So my question is, how would I write the filter in `soup.find_all()` to zoom into a class?

I apologize in advance if I had mixed up any terminology. This is my first time attempting web scraping. I was not sure what to look at within the documentation.

For reference, this is the website I am attempting to do web scraping on:
http://pd.appbank.net/ml39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a search for tags within a certain parent directly, but you can use a nested loop to get it done. First, get all `ul` tags with the class `list-box mb-3 spacer`, and then get all `div`s located under each one.

```
div_list = []

for ul in soup.find_all('ul', {'class' : 'list-box mb-3 spacer'}):
    div_list.extend(ul.find_all('div', {'class' : 'name'}))

print(div_list)
```

Comment: Would I be able to do something similar if I wanted to filter out parents that have children with certain matching strings? At the moment, I am looking at a page with multiple parents "spacer mb-5", and all of them have a child "title-border mb-3", but I only want to extract information from a parent that matches a certain string. Would SoupStrainer help here?

Comment: @Psignarok Possibly. You would have to do a `if tag.find(...):` (something along those lines).

Answer (score 0):

Since the [page](http://pd.appbank.net/ml39) has only one `<ul>` tag with class 'list-box mb-3 spacer'. You could first find the `<ul class="list-box mb-3 spacer">` tag and then find the respective `<div class="name">` within the `<ul class="list-box mb-3 spacer">` as:

`ulTag = soup.find("ul", attrs={"class": "list-box mb-3 spacer"})
divTags = ulTag.find_all("div", {"class": "name"})
print(divTags)`